# How to say "beginning of the month?"

Tags: translation

I've tried google translate, but it doesn't seem like what I'm trying to translate is quite right (at least I'm not sure if it's correct).

To say "end of the month", I have heard people say "这月底“，but is there a complement to that for "beginning of the month"?

Comment: 月初 is okay. I might also say 月头.

Comment: Are you trying to say the first day or days of a month? As beginning of the month changes it's meaning depending on context

Comment: @50-3 could you provide both?

Comment: 月初 is the proper word. To my ear 月头 sounds very dialectal and I've never heard it before.

Comment: Yes, 「月头」 sounds sort of dialectal. But it is definitely in use. Check this [link](http://www.zdic.net/c/8/94/168991.htm)

Comment: Do not use 月头， it is a weird way of saying this. Your source indicated it's only used in classical books.

Comment: I haven't heard it used in mandarin, but I know that this is a very common way of saying it in Cantonese

Comment: @tomriddle_1234 It's not weird to me and not just used in classical I think it's another example of regional usage. Someone commented that it's common in Cantonese and it's also common in Shanghainese. It might not be common in Mandarin though. That's why I put 月初 first.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of translations. What @agriprop said is probably the most common translation----**月初**----both in spoken and written Language.

月初 对应着 月末,月底(end of month)

What @CA55CE37 answered should not have `本`, here `本` means this month. You cannot use it to describe other month. However `月起` is not a word. I never heard. While `伊始` is a very formal word that we often used in written Chinese. [伊始](http://www.zdic.net/c/a/8/12020.htm) means the beginning. `伊始` is often used as adverb to describe that we begin to do something. The usage of `伊始`: verb+伊始----the beginning of doing something.

refer:

- http://www.nciku.com/search/zh/detail/%E6%9C%88%E5%88%9D/52961
- http://www.zdic.net/c/8/94/168956.htm

Answer (score 0):

Besides what hrzhu says, you can also say:

本月起，本月伊始

Comment: I didn't down-vote you. I would read 「本月起」 as starting from this month rather than the beginning of the month. 「本月伊始」 is okay, 「伊始」 sounds artsy to me though.

Comment: 伊始 is way too literary.

Comment: 伊始 is not too literary. It is common.

Comment: 「伊始」 is definitely common. It appears mostly in written form.